# NFS server into a docker container

Tags: ip, docker, nfs

I'm trying to run NFS server into a docker container. I used this container :

```
https://github.com/cpuguy83/docker-nfs-server
```

But I can't mount the directory. I tried to give an ip adresss  to my contaner with ifconfig vethaa1d6f9 172.xx.xx.xxx and I can ping this adress but it's impossible to mount a directory with

```
mount -t nfs 172.xx.xx.xxx:/Path
```

Do you have any Ideas how can I mount my directory and access to my container ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to get the ip of a docker container :

```
 docker inspect nfs22 | grep IP
```

And now I can mount my directory with mount -t nfs IP:/Path

I hope this will help you !